# How to increase arrow size of quiver plot and change the scale to describe magnitude instead of arrows?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am trying to visualize a WRF dataset to display the wind speed and direction. I am using contours and filled contours to visualize the wind speed, and am using arrows to visualize the wind direction. I have managed to do so, however the arrows from the quiver plot are extremely small, and they are very difficult to interpret. So my first question is, how do I change the size of the arrows in the quiver plot to make them more legible?

[Relevant quiver plot with small arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSj8m.png)

My second question also has to do with the quiver plot posted above. Notice on the right, the scale is from 0 to 1.0. I am unsure of what this is trying to visualize. Without the quiver plot, the scale is correct in visualizing the wind speed (see picture below).

[Wind speed with correct scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En6r3.png)

How do I get the correct scale (the one in figure 2) to display instead of the scale in figure 1? Here's the relevant code:

```
# Get WRF variables
wind_10m = getvar(ds, 'uvmet10_wspd_wdir', units='ms-1')[0,:]
test_wind = getvar(ds, 'uvmet10_wspd_wdir', units='ms-1')
wspd_10m = getvar(ds, 'uvmet10', units='ms-1')
wrf_lat, wrf_lon = latlon_coords(wind_10m)
wrf_lons = to_np(wrf_lon)
wrf_lats = to_np(wrf_lat)
x = wrf_lon.values
y = wrf_lat.values
u_comp = wspd_10m[0,:,:]
v_comp = wspd_10m[1,:,:]
u = u_comp.values
v = v_comp.values

# Normalize u and v components for quiver plot
u_norm = u / np.sqrt(u**2 + v**2)
v_norm = v /np.sqrt(u**2 + v**2)

# Timestamp
timestamp = to_np(wind_10m.Time).astype('M8[s]').astype('O').isoformat()
time = wind_10m.Time
time_str = str(time.values)

cart_proj = get_cartopy(wind_10m)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
ax = plt.axes(projection=cart_proj)
plt.contour(wrf_lons, wrf_lats, wind_10m, colors='black', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.contourf(wrf_lons, wrf_lats, wind_10m, cmap=get_cmap('rainbow'), transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.quiver(x, y, u_norm, v_norm, pivot='middle', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), regrid_shape=50)

plot_background(ax)

plt.colorbar(ax=ax, shrink=0.98)

ax.set_extent([-104.35, -94.45, 36.37, 44.78])
ax.set_title('10m Wind Speed and Direction (m/s) ' + time_str[:19])

plt.show()
```